# Proving both defining properties of a distibutive lattice are equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, lattice-orders

In class, we've defined distributive lattice to be a lattice L which verifies the following properties:
$$(1) \space \space a \wedge (b \vee c) = (a \wedge b) \vee ( a \wedge c)$$
$$(2) \space \space a \vee (b \wedge c) = (a \vee b) \wedge ( a \vee c) \quad \forall a,b,c \in L$$
But were asked to show that $(1) \Leftrightarrow (2)$.
I tried to prove $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ as follows:
$$ (a \vee b) \wedge ( a \vee c) =((a \vee b)\wedge a) \vee ((a \vee b)\wedge c)=(a \vee (a \wedge b)) \vee((a \wedge c)\vee (b \wedge c))=((a\wedge b)\vee (a\wedge c))\vee (a \vee (b\wedge c))=(a \wedge (b \vee c))\vee(a\vee(b\wedge c)) $$

On the third equal sign, I'm using only commutativity and associativity. Then, I regroup the first term using (1). I'm not implying $a\vee(a\wedge b)$ = $a\wedge(b\vee c)$ but rather $(a\wedge b)\vee(a\wedge c)= a\wedge(b\vee c)$

Now, because $a \wedge (b \vee c)\leq a $ and $a\vee(b\wedge c) \geq a$ the expression above equals $a\vee(b\wedge c)$ just as we wanted.

I'm not entirely convinced this reasoning is okay, though, in particular the final bit where I compare both terms at either sides of the join operator. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me clarify if this is correct. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to use other properties of the lattice. Please state what all of those other properties are. Also, please carefully state which properties you used in each step of your attempted proof. Only  then can we determine if your proof is correct.

Comment: What's not clear to me is how you got from $a \vee (a \wedge b)$  to $a \wedge (b \vee c)$... on thee 3rd equal sign; you're claiming these are equal.

Comment: @Somos I'll try to clarify what I did. In the first equality, I apply (1), which is assumed. Then I apply it again in each term, replace $a \wedge a$ with a, and reorder using commutativity. Finally, I use associativity and commutativity to reorder and apply (1) one last time. I'll edit the post to add intermediate steps so that it's easier to read, sorry about that. I think the only property of lattices I can use is that every subset of L with two elements has a supremum and an infimum.

Comment: @Fizz I've edited the post with an intermediate step, hope it's clearer this way.

Comment: No, it's not clearer.

Comment: On the third equal sign, I'm using only commutativity and associativity. Then, I regroup the first term using (1). I'm not implying $a \vee (a \wedge b) = a \wedge (b \vee c)$ but rather $(a\vee b) \vee (a\wedge c)= a \wedge (b\vee c)$

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, letting $x= a \wedge (b \vee c)$ and $y = a\vee(b\wedge c)$, your final argument is that $x \le a \le y$, so $x \lor y = y$. That seems fine.

... although the usual trick is to observe (at an earlier stage) that  $a \vee (a \wedge b) = a$ (i.e. using the [absorption law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)#Lattices_as_algebraic_structures) that holds in any kind of lattice), which simplifies the proof a bit (and applying that twice).

In fact you can still apply the absorption law to your expression but taking it over $b\lor c$ as the "stuff absorbed" into $a$, which provides alternative justification for your last step:

$$\overbrace{(a \wedge (b \vee c)) \lor a}\vee(b\wedge c) = 
a \vee(b\wedge c)\\$$

Answer (score -1):

Copy-paste of [my contribution 12 ears ago on the French Wikipedia page about lattices](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Treillis_(ensemble_ordonn%C3%A9)&oldid=53765053), which proves $(2)\implies(1):$
$$\begin{align}(a\land c)\lor(b\land c)&=[a\lor(b\land c)]\land[c\lor(b\land c)]\\&=(a\lor b)\land(a\lor c)\land c\\&=(a\lor b)\land c.\end{align}$$
The converse being dual, its proof is similar. You can find it for instance in [G. Birkhoff, *Lattice Theory*, Theorem 9, p.11](https://archive.org/details/latticetheory0000birk/page/11/mode/1up) (this reference was found [on the English Wikipedia page about distributive lattices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Definition)).