# Equivalent definitions of distributive lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

A lattice is an algebraic structure $(L, \wedge, \vee)$, consisting of a set $L$ and two binary, commutative and associative operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$ on $L$ satisfying the following identities for all $a,b \in L$:

ABS1: $a \wedge (a \vee b) = a$

ABS2: $a \vee (a \wedge b) = a$

A lattice $(L, \wedge, \vee)$ is distributive if it satisfies one of the following identities for all $a,b,c \in L$:

DISTR1: $a \wedge (b \vee c) = (a \wedge b) \vee (a \wedge c)$

DISTR2: $a \vee (b \wedge c) = (a \vee b) \wedge (a \vee c)$

How can I prove that a lattice that satisfies DISTR1 satisfies also DISTR2?

Edit: I can write
$$\begin{align}a \vee (b \wedge c) &= (a \vee (a \wedge c)) \vee (b \wedge c) \\&= a \vee ((a \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge c)) \\&= a \vee ((c \wedge a) \vee (c \wedge b)) \\&= a \vee (c \wedge (a \vee b))\end{align}$$
But I don't know how to conclude...

Comment: @AnneBauval: I can write
$a \vee (b \wedge c) = (a \vee (a \wedge c)) \vee (b \wedge c) = a \vee ((a \wedge c) \vee (b \wedge c)) = a \vee ((c \wedge a) \vee (c \wedge b)) = a \vee (c \wedge (a \vee b))$

But I don't know how to conclude...

Comment: Duplicate: [Proving both defining properties of a distibutive lattice are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4705707/386889).

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer ;-)